# android studio cannot find twitter certificate

Tags: android, twitter, android-studio, twitter-fabric

I get the error

```
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:390)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
    at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Authorization completed with an error
 com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
     at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:95)
     at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:215)
     at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.failure(Callback.java:45)
     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5837)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

And `Android Studio > Preferences > Server Certificates >` does not have any `Accepted Certificates`.

How do I add the certificate?

Comment: Can you share the code that triggers twitter and causes error?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the certificates on your device, rather than in Android Studio. What device are you running the App on?

Comment: I do not have much twitter code at all, only a login button and so the likely  culprit is `Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()`. As for the issue being with my device, it's not. It's with android studio. The code used to work, but after updating android studio it stops working. Android studio used to have a certificate, I forgot the name, maybe `untaken` on something like that. now it's gone.

Comment: Actually I think the name was untangle.

Comment: Did you set a valid callback URL to login request?

Comment: Yes. Everything used to work, so the setup is correct. It's the new android studio. So maybe I have to completely uninstall android studio and reinstall it: drastic, I know. But I am completely blocked.